# Selecting multiple products from the same category?

Tags: mysql, sql, innodb

**Statement Attempt 1:**

It seemed to ignore everything and get products from anywhere regardless of country

```
SELECT *
FROM products
WHERE `country` = 'America' AND
      product = 'Product 1' AND
      product = 'Product 2' AND
      completed = 'complete'
```

**Statement Attempt 2:**

The result of this was that is returned 0 results, even though the results are there hypothetically.

```
SELECT *
FROM products
WHERE `country` = 'America' AND
      product = 'Product 1' OR
      product = 'Product 2' AND
      completed = 'complete'
```

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and an explanation of what you want to do would really help.

Comment: There's an order of precedence for boolean operators: `()-NOT-AND-OR`, you might want `WHERE country = 'America' AND
      (product = 'Product 1' OR
      product = 'Product 2') AND
      completed = 'complete'`, which is the same as `WHERE country = 'America' AND
      product IN ('Product 1',
      'Product 2') AND
      completed = 'complete'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first query is logically incorrect due to `product = product 1 AND product = product 2`, where clause filter rows one by one, so a single row at same time cannot contain both values in product column.

---

Your second query has an issue that you introduced and `OR` criteria so it ignores the country filter if there is product 2 with status completed in another country , to correct your query you need to group your `OR` criteria by using parenthesis `(condition 1 or condition 2) and some other condition`

```
SELECT *
FROM products
WHERE `country` = 'America'
      AND (product = 'Product 1' OR product = 'Product 2')
      AND completed = 'complete'
```

Or you could use `IN` clause to simplify your criteria

```
SELECT *
FROM products
WHERE `country` = 'America'
      AND product IN('Product 1','Product 2')
      AND completed = 'complete'
```